# Adding images to my array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I would like to know if there's any way to add images to the arrays of my Slot machine? Right now i've just been able to add numbers in the array.

So far i got this, i know there's only one choice in my array, it's on purpose:

```js
var arr = ["#7.png"];

// var arr = [5];
var credits = 10;

function freezeCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById("hold1").checked == true || document.getElementById("hold2").checked == true || document.getElementById("hold3").checked == true) {
    // if any is checked, freeze hold buttons.
    document.getElementById("hold1").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("hold2").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("hold3").checked = false;

    document.getElementById("hold1").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("hold2").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("hold3").disabled = true;
  } else if (document.getElementById("hold1").disabled == true) {
    // if any diabled, enable (unfreeze) all hold buttons.
    document.getElementById("hold1").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("hold2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("hold3").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("reel1").classList.remove('hold');
    document.getElementById("reel2").classList.remove('hold');
    document.getElementById("reel3").classList.remove('hold');
  }
};

function getNumbers() {
  if(document.getElementById("hold1").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("reel1").innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  } if (document.getElementById("hold2").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("reel2").innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  } if (document.getElementById("hold3").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("reel3").innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }

  updateScore();
  insertCoins();
};

function calculateScore() {
    document.getElementById('credits').innerHTML = credits;
}

    // Win, three alike.
function updateScore() {
    if(document.getElementById("reel1").textContent == document.getElementById("reel2").textContent && document.getElementById("reel1").textContent == document.getElementById("reel3").textContent){
      credits += document.getElementById("reel1").textContent * 10;
    } else if("reel1" != "reel2"){
      credits -= 2;
    }
};

function insertCoins() {
  if (credits <1){
    document.getElementById("spin").disabled = true;
  }
};

function freezeReel(num) {
  if (document.getElementById('hold'+num).checked == true) {
    // Unfreeze reel
    document.getElementById("hold"+num).checked = false;
    document.getElementById("reel"+num).classList.remove('hold');
  } else {
    // Freeze reel:
    document.getElementById("hold"+num).checked = true;
    document.getElementById("reel"+num).classList.add('hold');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.marginauto {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.button-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
}
.hold-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 48px;
}
.holdbutton {
  width: 140px;
  height: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.credits {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.reel-wrapper {
  width: 1280px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.button {
  background-color: white;
}
.reels {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.reels.hold {
  border-color: blue;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <input id="spin" type="button" onClick="getNumbers(); freezeCheck(); calculateScore();" value="Spin" />
  </div>
  <div class="reel-wrapper marginauto">
    <div id="reel1" onClick="freezeReel(1);" class="reels"></div>
    <div id="reel2" onClick="freezeReel(2);" class="reels"></div>
    <div id="reel3" onClick="freezeReel(3);" class="reels"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hold-wrapper">
    <input id="hold1" type="checkbox" value="Hold" class="holdbutton" />
    <input id="hold2" type="checkbox" value="Hold" class="holdbutton" />
    <input id="hold3" type="checkbox" value="Hold" class="holdbutton" />
  </div>
    <div class="credits">Your Credits: <span id="credits"></span></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Couple of comments:  * if what you want is to show images embed them inside reel* divs and change src attribute to show them. It's ok to use the url of the images in your script. * There is no need to check againts true value, don't use "if (something == true)", use "if (something)". PS: To add elements to an array there is a "push" function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `backgroundImage` javascript property and provide value with a source from the array `arr`.

Refer code:

```js
var arr = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png'];

var credits = 10;

function freezeCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById("hold1").checked == true || document.getElementById("hold2").checked == true || document.getElementById("hold3").checked == true) {
    // if any is checked, freeze hold buttons.
    document.getElementById("hold1").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("hold2").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("hold3").checked = false;

    document.getElementById("hold1").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("hold2").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("hold3").disabled = true;
  } else if (document.getElementById("hold1").disabled == true) {
    // if any diabled, enable (unfreeze) all hold buttons.
    document.getElementById("hold1").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("hold2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("hold3").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("reel1").classList.remove('hold');
    document.getElementById("reel2").classList.remove('hold');
    document.getElementById("reel3").classList.remove('hold');
  }
};

function getNumbers() {
  if(document.getElementById("hold1").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("reel1").backgroundImage = "url(" + arr[0] + ")";
  } if (document.getElementById("hold2").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("reel2").backgroundImage = "url(" + arr[1] + ")";
  } if (document.getElementById("hold3").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("reel3").backgroundImage = "url(" + arr[2] + ")";
  }

  updateScore();
  insertCoins();
};

function calculateScore() {
    document.getElementById('credits').innerHTML = credits;
}

    // Win, three alike.
function updateScore() {
    if(document.getElementById("reel1").textContent == document.getElementById("reel2").textContent && document.getElementById("reel1").textContent == document.getElementById("reel3").textContent){
      credits += document.getElementById("reel1").textContent * 10;
    } else if("reel1" != "reel2"){
      credits -= 2;
    }
};

function insertCoins() {
  if (credits <1){
    document.getElementById("spin").disabled = true;
  }
};

function freezeReel(num) {
  if (document.getElementById('hold'+num).checked == true) {
    // Unfreeze reel
    document.getElementById("hold"+num).checked = false;
    document.getElementById("reel"+num).classList.remove('hold');
  } else {
    // Freeze reel:
    document.getElementById("hold"+num).checked = true;
    document.getElementById("reel"+num).classList.add('hold');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.marginauto {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.button-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
}
.hold-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 48px;
}
.holdbutton {
  width: 140px;
  height: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.credits {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.reel-wrapper {
  width: 1280px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.button {
  background-color: white;
}
.reels {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.reels.hold {
  border-color: blue;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <input id="spin" type="button" onClick="getNumbers(); freezeCheck(); calculateScore();" value="Spin" />
  </div>
  <div class="reel-wrapper marginauto">
    <div id="reel1" onClick="freezeReel(1);" class="reels"></div>
    <div id="reel2" onClick="freezeReel(2);" class="reels"></div>
    <div id="reel3" onClick="freezeReel(3);" class="reels"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hold-wrapper">
    <input id="hold1" type="checkbox" value="Hold" class="holdbutton" />
    <input id="hold2" type="checkbox" value="Hold" class="holdbutton" />
    <input id="hold3" type="checkbox" value="Hold" class="holdbutton" />
  </div>
    <div class="credits">Your Credits: <span id="credits"></span></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` stands for standard font in your page and it will only shows text. Since in your array, the value of it is `#7.png` and it will only display #7.png.
Adding the following code will create img tag in your html code with the images being random.

```
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]);
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Slotimg");
document.getElementById("reel1").appendChild(elem);
```

However if you can create a default image, i would suggest you just add a Img tag in your div, and just change the `src` attribute by src code, it is going to be much easier and effiecnt